# Is the path with the highest average value the same as the path with the lowest total difference from the function's maximum?

Tags: calculus, geometry

If you have a function $f(x, y)$ and you draw two paths (curved lines) from points A to B where:

- The first path is the path with the highest average value (if the value at distance $d$ from the start is represented by the function $g(d)$ and $l$ is the total length, then $\frac{\int_{0}^{l}g(d)\ dd}{l}$would be the highest)
- The second path is the path with the lowest total value of the difference between the value at a point and the maximum value of the function (if the value at distance $d$ from the start was represented by the function $g(d)$, $l$ is the total length and $m$ is the maximum value of the function ${\int_{0}^{l}m-g(d)\ dd}$ would be the lowest)

Would these two paths be identical? How could you prove/disprove this?

I'm guessing that this problem could be simplified by inverting the function and adding its highest value to it, to get rid of the $m-g(d)$.

Comment: Normally the integrals in both parts would be over the range of $x$ coordinates from A to B, not over the length of the path. That would give the usual interpretation of the average of a function.  You are integrating $dx$, which is not guaranteed to continue as long as $\ell $.  Let $A=(0,0), B=(1,0)$ and the path be a semicircle.  As the semicircle length is $\pi$, your integral asks for $g(\pi-\epsilon)$, but as a function of $x$.  which may not exist because the path is only defined from $x=0$ to $x=1$.  I think you need to sort this out and work on the question.

Comment: Somebody voted to close this as off-topic, but did not leave a comment.  I think there are problems with the question, which I detailed above, but it seems on-topic to me.

Comment: @RossMillikan: $g(x)$ is guaranteed to continue up to $l$, as $g(x)$ gives the value at the point that is $x$ away from the start of the path **if we follow it**.

Answer (score 0):

The first path not well defined.  We might as well let $A=(0,0), B=(1,0)$  Consider the path that goes from $A$ to $(1/2,h)$ in a straight line and then descends to $B$ in a straight line.  $\ell=2\sqrt{h^2+\frac 14}$  The average height is $\frac h2$, which I can make as large as I want.

For the second, if $A$ and $B$ have the same $y$ value, the optimum is the straight segment from $A$ to $B$, where the error is zero.  If they are at different $y$ values, you should draw a(n almost) vertical line from the lower to the $y$ value of the higher, then a horizontal segment to the higher.

Comment: Why are the two paths necessarily the same length? $l$ is not a constant, it is the length of the path that gives the highest/lowest value for that expression.

Comment: I assumed $\ell$ would be constant, but see you did not impose that.  I will replace the answer.